# How to redefine the proof environment for INFORMS papers

Tags: environments, journal

In almost all journals, proofs are written in a "proof" environment, like this"

```
\begin{proof}
PROOF BODY
\end{proof}
```

But INFORMS journals have an idiosyncratic way of writing proofs:

```
\proof{Proof.} 
PROOF BODY
\Halmos
\endproof
```

When I submit a paper to an INFORMS journal, instead of going over all the "proof" environments in my paper and changing them, I thought of just re-defining the "proof" environments to use the INFORMS macros:

```
\renewenvironment{proof}
{
    \proof{Proof.} 
}
{ 
    \Halmos
    \endproof
}
```

But it did not work: I got an error "TeX capacity exceeded".

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Can you be more precise about the template you're using? A link and the name of the document class should suffice.

Comment: The template is here: https://pubsonline.informs.org/pb-assets/Operations-Research-template-1489419504023.zip  The first line is \documentclass[opre,nonblindrev]{informs3}

Comment: In the preamble of your latex document, do give `\let\proof\relax \let\endproof\relax \let\theoremstyle\relax \usepackage{amsthm}` a try. That should load the "standard" `proof` environment of the `amsthm` package.

Comment: The definitions made by the class are (insert word here). Well, disputable. By the way, the version of the class I have is from 2012, about 17 years since `\bf`, `\it` and similar commands had been deprecated.

Comment: @Mico It worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(re-posting an earlier comment so that this question can be considered to have received (at least) one formal answer.)

The `informs3` document class makes a number of, to put it delicately, questionable layout decisions. One of them, as you've discovered, is the particular form of the `proof` environment.

Rather than reinvent the wheel, so to speak, I suggest you load the `amsthm` package to allow you to use its time-proven `proof` environment. To do this, just executed the next few instructions in the preamble:

```
\let\proof\relax 
\let\endproof\relax 
\let\theoremstyle\relax 
\usepackage{amsthm}
```